# Three.js assign array of materials to an indexed BufferGeometry

Tags: three.js

I have a BufferGeometry triangular prism; where I have specified the 6 vertices and then added indexes to create the 8 faces (2 triangle faces per square plane).

I have then setup 5 groups, so that each side of the prism is a group.

And it works here when I have a single material assigned to the whole object: https://jsfiddle.net/30ez17dw/1/

However I want to be able to assign an array of materials, so that each side (`group`) has it's own materials.  But when I do this the object disappears:

https://jsfiddle.net/30ez17dw/2/

How can I fix my code to make the array of materials work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not specified your groups correctly. Try it like so:

```js
var camera, scene, renderer;

init();
animate();

function init() {

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10);
  camera.position.z = 5;
  camera.position.y = 2;
  camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);

  scene = new THREE.Scene();


  var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

  const y = 0.866025404;
  const y2 = 0.5;
  const h = 1;

  const vertices = new Float32Array([
    -y2, 0, 0,
    y2, 0, 0,
    0, 0, y,

    -y2, h, 0,
    y2, h, 0,
    0, h, y,
  ]);

  const indices = [
    0, 1, 2, // Top
    5, 4, 3, // Bottom
    3, 1, 0, // Back
    1, 3, 4, // Back
    0, 2, 3, // Left
    5, 3, 2, // Left
    4, 2, 1, // Right
    2, 4, 5, // Right
  ];


  geometry.setAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(vertices, 3));
  geometry.setIndex(indices);

  geometry.computeVertexNormals();

  geometry.clearGroups();
  geometry.addGroup(0, 3, 0);
  geometry.addGroup(3, 6, 1);
  geometry.addGroup(6, 12, 2);
  geometry.addGroup(12, 18, 3);
  geometry.addGroup(18, 24, 4);

  var material = [
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      color: 0x00ff00
    }),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      color: 0xff0000
    }),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      color: 0x0000ff,
    }),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      color: 0xffff00
    }),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      color: 0x00ffff
    })

  ];

  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material); // , side: THREE.DoubleSide
  scene.add(mesh);

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
  });
  renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

}

function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.132.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

The indices you pass to `addGroup()` are meant to be consecutive.